# changing value of a tag through XML parser

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I am new to XML. I want to change the value of a tag in an xml file. I am using Xerces c++ library for this purpose. Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of a tag"? Do you mean the name of an element? Or do you mean the value that appears between a start tag and an end tag?

Comment: You can change XML nodes (elements as well) thorugh the standard DOM. Xerces implements that standard

Comment: the value that appears between a start tag and an end tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load the XML document: `xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("temp.xml");`

get the tag "tag1" you want to write (first one):`DOMNode x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tag1")[0];`

get the value node: `DOMNode y=x.childNodes[0];`

change the value of this node: `y.nodeValue="New Value";`

Comment: what do you mean by first one

Comment: the getElementsByTagName return a list of Nodes with the name specified. So if you have Tag name which is not unique, this line of code give you the first node.

Comment: By the way, try normalizeDocument() to save the change.

Comment: how to use normalizeDocument(). Can you please elaborate something about it?